# Making a card clickable without underlining everything

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a clickable card interface to list different articles. I'm unable to make the entire area of each card clickable without all text in the card being underlined.

[Here is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hff1y.png)

I've played around with the different divs and `position:relative;` as I've read that doing so while making the links ::after code absolute is another way to do it. Any help or pointers appreciated.

Here is my CSS:

```
.main{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards_item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;

}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;

}

.card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
    position:relative;

}

.card_title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height:1rem;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card_text {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;    
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* link */

.fullclick li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

}
.fullclick a {
    text-decoration:none !important;


}
.fullclick a.main {
  color: #85baff;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration:none !important;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.fullclick li a.main::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card"><a class="fullclick" href="https://pressley.house.gov/2023/02/21/pressley-advocates-survivors-of-marathon-bombing-celebrate-passage-of-congresswomans-post-disaster-mental-health-response-act/">
        <div class="card_image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10"></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Pressley, Advocates, Survivors of Marathon Bombing Celebrate Passage of Congresswoman’s Post Disaster Mental Health Response Act</h2>
          <p class="card_text">February 21, 2023</p>
        </div>
      </a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can view the page at https://namimass.org/press/, pass is "hello"

What am I missing here?

Comment: `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @epascarello: no, does not work. thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your styling definitions are a little messed up.

For example you're using `.fullclick a{}` when `.fullclick` is being applied to the anchor tag. So it should be `a.fullclick{}`.

You also have some definitions that would never be applied due to the hierarchy of your HTML vs your css definitions. Example `.fullclick a.main` where your `.main` class is a parent of the `.fullclick` class in your HTML.

```css
.main{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards_item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;

}

@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 56rem) {
  .cards_item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;

}

.card_content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
    position:relative;

}

.card_title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height:1rem;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card_text {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;    
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* link */

.fullclick li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

}
.fullclick{
    text-decoration:none !important;


}
.fullclick a.main {
  color: #85baff;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration:none !important;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.fullclick li a.main::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="cards_item">
      <div class="card"><a class="fullclick" href="https://pressley.house.gov/2023/02/21/pressley-advocates-survivors-of-marathon-bombing-celebrate-passage-of-congresswomans-post-disaster-mental-health-response-act/">
        <div class="card_image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10"></div>
        <div class="card_content">
          <h2 class="card_title">Pressley, Advocates, Survivors of Marathon Bombing Celebrate Passage of Congresswoman’s Post Disaster Mental Health Response Act</h2>
          <p class="card_text">February 21, 2023</p>
        </div>
      </a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Right- I see that now. I've gotten rid of the .main modifier and moved a. to be in front of .fullclick as you suggested. It is now working and there's no underline! I appreciate your help and patience.